# Google OAuth token exchange returns invalid_code

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I have been implementing the Google web server OAuth flow, but when I attempted to exchange the authorization code with access token, it always complains "invalid_code".

Here is the issue:

**Step 1:**

Redirect one of our pages to 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=email&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyurl.com%2Fcallback&response_type=code&client_id=some_client_id'

**Step 2:**

The redirection happens and google would redirect to our url 
https://myurl.com/callback?code=somecode

**Step 3:**

curl -X POST --data "code=somecode&client_id=some_client_id&some_client_secret=some_client_secret&redirect_uri=https://myurl.com/callback&grant_type=authorization_code" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token -v --trace-ascii /dev/stout

The response comes back:

HTTP 400 Bad request

{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Invalid code."
}

Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The life span of authorization code is only 10 mins,and can only be used one time. So do these checks:

1. Do you use it 10 min later? If so, use it in 10 mins.
2. Have you used it before? If so, obtain a new one and then use it.
3. Is you server time in sync with Google OAuth server's? If not, change your time.

Comment: It turned out to be number 2.  Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 2):

I was using http://localhost:8080 as my redirect url since I was just trying out their examples. And my json file contents had this:

```
"redirect_uris": [
  "http://localhost:8080"
],
"javascript_origins": [
  "http://localhost:8080"
]
```

In the developer console I had the redirect_uri set to "http://localhost:8080" and I was getting the same error. I changed it to "http://localhost:8080/" and then it started working. (Essentially adding a '/' at the end.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you not notice the '/' at the end? I know it sounds crazy, but it worked for me.

Comment: Apparently not.  Probably good to explain, as you just have, just in case.... since it is, really the important facet you're trying to communicate.

Comment: Makes sense. Added a line. Thanks!